# 好きだ or 好きな: which one to be used in the below mentioned sentence

Tags: conjugations, na-adjectives

[image]

Which one is correct?
私が好きだ日本の食べ物はてんぷらです。
Or
私が好きな日本の食べ物はてんぷらです。

I am not sure whether to use sukina or sukida 
Please post your answer with explaination.
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

好きな

It's being used attributively, to modify "Japanese food". 好きだ is used predicatively.　だ is the copula, so 好きだ almost always occurs at the end of a sentence. It cannot be used before nouns to modify them.

Comment: Perhaps it would be valuable to elaborate on when it would be proper to use 好きだ .